# How to Compare Excel values with iframe Dropdown values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Have one scenario i.e., Need to compare excel values with Dropdown values (DD present in iFrame). I have done code but this was very very slow and need to optimize for quick comparison. Here list is having all the datas from Dropdown. Thanks in Advance.

code for reference:

```
for (int k = 1; k<= totalrows;k++)
        {
            XSSFCell Cell=sheetname.getRow(k).getCell(0);
            Cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            String Celldata=Cell.getStringCellValue();
            boolean isfound = false;
            webDD:
            for(WebElement e : list)    {
                String CliNam = e.getText();
                if(findClientNam.equals(Celldata))
                {
                    isfound= true;
                    break webDD;
                }
            }               
            if(!isfound)
            {
                Log.info("Value Not found in Dropdown: "+Celldata);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over `List<WebElement>` for each row make `Set<String>` and use the `contains`

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
for(WebElement e : list) {
    values.add(e.getText());
}  

for (int k = 1 ; k <= totalrows ; k++) {
    XSSFCell Cell = sheetname.getRow(k).getCell(0);
    Cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    String cellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();

    if (!values.contains(cellData)) {
        Log.info("Value Not found in Dropdown: " + cellData);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks yar. Now it was faster. :)

Comment: @TestEngg You should also consider removing the `Thread.sleep;`, it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again.